# eval ('1+1') works in JavaScript but not in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, eval

I use `eval('1+1')` without any issue in JavaScript but for some reason I can't get this to work in PHP. This is an internal (non-public) webpage so security is not an issue. No matter how I code it I am seeing an 500 Internal Server Error.

I'm trying to do something like this in a PHP file:

```
$expression='1+1';

echo "eval($expression)";
```

Is the `eval()` function in PHP not the same as the JavaScript equivalent or is it perhaps not as straightforward to implement?

Comment: Why do you have the eval call in quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following code:

```
$expression='1+1';
echo "eval($expression)";
```

Since you're quoting the `eval()` statement, it'd just print `eval(1+1)` literally.

`eval()` needs a valid expression.

You're probably looking for:

```
$expression='1+1'; 
echo eval("echo $expression;");
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/55649)

Comment: Ah, you beat me before I could fix mine. I knew mine didn't look right.

Comment: I'm not clear why the code: eval("echo $expression;"); actually outputs the results (as opposed to storing it in a variable). That being said, is there a way to store the result instead of echoing it?

Comment: @KenBoone: `eval()` executes arbitrary PHP code. In this case, the code is `echo $expression`. `$expression` will have the output of `1+1` and the code will just print out 2. If you want to store the result in a variable, then you can do something like this: `eval("\$var = $expression;");` -- this will store the result in a variable and you can re-use it later, if you want to. See a demo here: https://eval.in/56676 (**don't** use `eval()` if it involves user input somewhere. It's [**dangerous**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951373/1438393).)

Answer (score 1):

eval() function must have as argument a valid php code, see this example:

```
echo eval("return 1+1;");
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Note that the `eval()` function is very dangerous, regardless of internal server or not, be careful.

Now, `eval()` in PHP allows executing of PHP code. What you're doing is echoing executing PHP code.

That said, try this:

```
$expression = "1+1";
echo eval("echo $expression;");
```

Comment: Yeah...I'm trying it. I'll be deleting this in a sec, I think.

Comment: Thanks Amal, was just doing that.

Answer (score 0):

`eval()` executes PHP code, not just about anything like any arbitrary mathematical expression. 
`1+1` is not a valid PHP code expression. So give it proper PHP expression to execute.
like:

```
$expression='echo 1+1;'; 
eval($expression);
```

> Valid PHP code to be evaluated.

**[Reference](http://php.net/eval)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
eval('$expression =1+1;');
echo $expression;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$expression = "1+1";

$result = " return (".$expression.")
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: The code won't evaluate anything. Did you try to run it before posting it?